# Why do the XMLHttpRequest open and send not called using javascript in Android?

Tags: javascript, android, webview, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to intercept a POST request before opening an HTML page using webView.
I followed the tutorial on: https://medium.com/@madmuc/intercept-all-network-traffic-in-webkit-on-android-9c56c9262c85
which injects the javascript file through a .js file in the assets folder:

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.origOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, password) {
    // these will be the key to retrieve the payload
    this.recordedMethod = method;
    this.recordedUrl = url;
    this.origOpen(method, url, async, user, password);

};
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.origSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(body) {
    // interceptor is a Kotlin interface added in WebView
    if(body) recorder.recordPayload(this.recordedMethod, this.recordedUrl, body);
    this.origSend(body);
};
```

However, the open and send are never called, I added logs to test and if I move the  `recorder.recordPayload(...)` (which is the method in the javascript interface) out of those functions then `recordPayload` is called, so the problem is not with the interface or reading from the file.

**webView class:**

````
class TestWebView : WebView {
    private var urlReturned = false
    private var postbackUrl: String? = "https://www.xxxxx.com"
    private var postbackHandled = false```

    lateinit var recorder: PayloadRecorder
    lateinit var payload: String

    constructor(context: Context?) : super(context) {
        initUI()
    }

    private fun initUI() {
        if (!isInEditMode) {
            settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
            settings.builtInZoomControls = true
            settings.displayZoomControls = false
            settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
            settings.useWideViewPort = true

            recorder = PayloadRecorder()
            addJavascriptInterface(recorder, "recorder")
            evaluateJavascript(
                context.assets.open("override.js").reader().readText(), null

            )
        }


        val client: WebViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {

            override fun shouldInterceptRequest(
                view: WebView,
                request: WebResourceRequest
            ): WebResourceResponse? {

                val payload = recorder.getPayload(request.method, request.url.toString())
                // handle the request with the given payload and return the response

                return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request)
            }

            override fun onPageStarted(
                view: WebView,
                url: String,
                favicon: Bitmap?
            ) {
                Log.i("testURL", url)


                evaluateJavascript(
                    context.assets.open("override.js").reader().readText(),
                    object : ValueCallback<String> {
                        override fun onReceiveValue(value: String?) {
                            Log.i("onReceiveValue", value)

                        }
                    }
                )
            }

        }

        setWebChromeClient(object : WebChromeClient() {
            override fun onConsoleMessage(consoleMessage: ConsoleMessage): Boolean {
                Log.d("WebView", consoleMessage.message())
                return true
            }
        })


    }


    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(
        context,
        attrs
    ) {
        initUI()
    }

    constructor(
        context: Context?,
        attrs: AttributeSet?,
        defStyle: Int
    ) : super(context, attrs, defStyle) {
        initUI()
    }

    constructor(
        context: Context?,
        attrs: AttributeSet?,
        defStyle: Int,
        privateBrowsing: Boolean
    ) : super(context, attrs, defStyle) {
        initUI()
    }


    class PayloadRecorder {
        private val payloadMap: MutableMap<String, String> =
            mutableMapOf()

        @JavascriptInterface
        fun recordPayload(
            method: String,
            url: String,
            payload: String
        ) {
            payloadMap["$method-$url"] = payload
            Log.i("payloadRecorder", "recordPayLoad")
        }

        fun getPayload(
            method: String,
            url: String
        ): String? =
            payloadMap["$method-$url"]
    }



    /**
     * The function that is called and starts the html progress
     */
    @JvmOverloads
    fun process(
        acsUrl: String?,
        md: String?,
        paReq: String?,
        postbackUrl: String? = null
    ) {
        urlReturned = false
        postbackHandled = false

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(postbackUrl)) {
            this.postbackUrl = postbackUrl
        }
        val postParams: String
        payload = paReq?: ""
        postParams =  //my code

        postUrl(acsUrl, postParams.toByteArray())
    }


    }
````

`recordPayload` is never called therefore in  `shouldInterceptRequest` `payload` always comes back null.

Comment: where are you setting in the webview settings "setJavaScriptEnabled" ?

Comment: as in ```webview.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true ```

Comment: @LenaBru it's there in initUI()

Comment: You will probably want to investigate the JavaScript that sends the POST requests. `XMLHttpRequest` is just one way of making HTTP calls in JavaScript. For example, the `fetch` API is meant to replace the `XMLHttpRequest`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API
It is also possible that the POST request is sent by HTML form submit call. First, find out how the POST requests are sent then try to override the functions.

Comment: I am having the same issue, any success?